# "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv'" when using Python.h

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api, python-embedding

When messing around with Python.h I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv'
```

C++ code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"  
#include "C:/Python27/include/Python.h"  
#include <iostream>  

using namespace std;  


int main()  
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys\nprint sys.argv[0]");
}
```

Which in Python is:

```
import sys
print sys.argv[0]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Conceptually, `sys.argv` should contain the arguments that Python was called with (and what it was called under).  What should it have if it were called like this, though?

You can load the calling program's `argv` into `sys`, if you want:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv);
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys\nprint sys.argv");
}
```

gives

```
localhost-2:argv $ ./a.out
['./a.out']
localhost-2:argv $ ./a.out arg0 17
['./a.out', 'arg0', '17']
```

See also `Py_SetProgramName`.