# Error, when using matplotlib in a python script embedded in a C++ program

Tags: python, c++, matplotlib

I have a python script which is invoked inside a C++ application. When I import matplotlib I get the following error.

> List index out of range.

In my script the only `matplotlib`related code is

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f = plt.figure()
```

When I invoke the script on its own it works. I get this exception only when it is embedded in a C++ Program. Do I need to provide some extra dependencies when the script uses matplotlib?

When I comment out the `matplotlib`functions I don't get the exception

**Update**

The C++ Code is from the python docs [link : 1.3. Pure Embedding](https://docs.python.org/3.8/extending/embedding.html)

I haven't modified anything from the C++ code. It works as long as there are no matplotlib related code.

Comment: can you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: how do you embed it in c++?

Comment: updated the post.

Comment: 1.3 Pure Embedding I have mentioned that in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the backend used by `matplotlib` is `tk` in my case. The window initialization of the `tk` has this code in there

```py
baseName = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
```

And in my case the argv is empty and that is the reason for `list index out of range` error.

One work around I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537291/embedding-python-with-c). We can passing dummy values like this:

```py
    wchar_t const *dummy_args[] = { L"Python", NULL };  // const is needed because literals must not be modified
    wchar_t const **argv = dummy_args;
    int             argc = sizeof(dummy_args) / sizeof(dummy_args[0]) - 1;
    PySys_SetArgv(argc, const_cast<wchar_t **>(argv));
```